# Laravel redirecting a user after register doesn't work when Registered event is fired

Tags: laravel

My `register` method of the `RegisterController`:

```php
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    $user = $this->create($request->all());

    Auth::login($user);

    event(new Registered($user));

    return redirect()->route('account.index'); 
}
```

If I go through this flow the user is authenticated and the event is fired, but the user is not redirected... Now for the confusing part: if I move the redirect line above the event line, it does work (but obviously the event doesn't fire):

```php
Auth::login($user);

return redirect()->route('account.index'); // User is correctly redirected here

event(new Registered($user));
```

What's happening here?

Full **RegisterController**:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        $user = $this->create($request->all());

        Auth::login($user);

        event(new Registered($user));

        return redirect()->route('account.index');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data, array $ua)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        ]);

        return $user;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using queue in event?

Answer (score 1):

Try to authenticate user with id :

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
    $user = $this->create($request->all());

    Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);

    event(new Registered($user));

    return redirect()->route('account.index'); 
}
```